# load a file, default location of netbeans

Tags: java

i'm using a IDE netbeans to run a java testing program to load a file. The following code is to to that

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();


        if (source==carMenuItem) {

            String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the file name");
            File file = new File(filename);
            System.out.println(file.isFile());
        }
    } 
}
```

but i'm using netbeans, where should i place the file in order to test the program successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to find out:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```